# Additional paths in msbuild script

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration

How to specify additional assembly reference paths for the MSBuild tasks?

I have following script so far, but can't figure out how to specify additional search paths.

```
<ItemGroup>
 <ProjectsToBuild Include="..\Main\Main.sln" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- The follwing paths should be added to reference search paths for the build tasks -->
<ItemGroup>
 <MyAddRefPath Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Build\Lib1" />
 <MyAddRefPath Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Build\Lib2" />
</ItemGroup>

<MSBuild
 Projects="@(ProjectsToBuild)"
 Properties="Configuration=Debug;OutputPath=$(BuildOutputPath)">
</MSBuild>
```

UPDATE:

Please show one complete working script which invokes original project, such as an SLN with multiple additional reference paths.

No suggestions on how to improve the project structure please.
I know how to build a good structure, but now it's the task of building an existing piece of crap.

Answer (score 5):

I have finaly figured out how to do it:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectsToBuild Include="ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalReferencePaths Include="..\Build\ClassLibrary1" />
    <AdditionalReferencePaths Include="..\Build\ClassLibrary2" />
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildOutputPath>..\Build\ConsoleApplication1</BuildOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="MainBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <AdditionalReferencePathsProp>@(AdditionalReferencePaths)</AdditionalReferencePathsProp>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuild
        Projects="ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.csproj"
        Properties="ReferencePath=$(AdditionalReferencePathsProp);OutputPath=$(BuildOutputPath)"
    >
    </MSBuild>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've stated that you want to be able to modify the assembly search paths without modifying the project files directly. In order to accomplish that requirement you need to set an environment variable that will override the AssemblySearchPaths. With this technique you will need to provide *every* assembly reference path used by all the projects in the solutions. (Modifying the projects or copies of the projects would be easier. See final comments.)

One technique is to create a batch file that runs your script at sets the environment variable:

```
set AssemblySearchPaths="C:\Tacos;C:\Burritos;C:\Chalupas"
msbuild whatever.msbuild
```

Another way is to define a PropertyGroup in your custom msbuild file (otherwise known as the "hook" needed to make this work):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectsToBuild Include="..\Main\Main.sln" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
          <AssemblySearchPaths>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Build\Lib1;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Build\Lib2</AssemblySearchPaths>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectsToBuild)" Properties="AssemblySearchPaths=$(AssemblySearchPaths);Configuration=Debug;OutputPath=$(OutputPath)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Now if it were me, and for whatever unexplained reason I couldn't modify the project files to include the updated references that I am going to build with, I would make copies of the project files, load them into the IDE, and correct the references in *my* copies. Synching the projects becomes a simple diff/merge operation which is automatic with modern tools like mercurial (heck I'm sure clearcase could manage it too).

Comment: Yes, in a perfect world i would reference the projects

Comment: @George - Why can't you add the references to the projects? How do you build?

Answer (score 1):

The property you want to modify is **AssemblySearchPaths**. See the [ResolveAssemblyReference task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad3f294%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) more information.

```
<Target Name="AddToSearchPaths">  
  <CreateProperty Value="x:\path\to\assemblies;$(AssemblySearchPaths)">  
    <Output PropertyName="AssemblySearchPaths" TaskParameter="Value" />  
  </CreateProperty>  
</Target>
```

Making use of item groups, as in your example, it would look like:

```
<Target Name="AddToSearchPaths">  
  <CreateProperty Value="@(MyAddRefPath);$(AssemblySearchPaths)">  
    <Output PropertyName="AssemblySearchPaths" TaskParameter="Value" />  
  </CreateProperty>  
</Target>
```

Looking in %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Common.targets, you can see that the [ResolveAssemblyReference Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad3f294%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is executed as part of the **ResolveAssemblyReferences** target. Thus, you want the newly added target to modify the AssemblySearchPaths property before **ResolveAssemblyReferences** is executed.

Comment: When the AddToSearchPath target supposed to be invoked? How does it relate to the original script? Did you try this?

Comment: He didn't add the hook. You'd need to do that in a project. Did you look into the ResolveAssemblyReferenceTask? The AssemblySearchPath is part of that target. This is a decent answer. If it doesn't meet your needs somehow, please add more details in your question. We all want to help. I like MSBuild, and like to help find solutions to problems with it.

Comment: No, adding a hook in the project is not a correct answer. I need to invoke them in a 'wrapper' without modifications to the original projects.

Comment: My answer is updated. I've shown the hook. So has @Spider M9.

Comment: From your question, I had no idea you could not modify the project file; that changes things considerably. Looks like Spider M9 has taken care of it.

Answer (score 0):

...and remember that you don't need to use a target for this, you can use project-scoped properties or items, as...

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MyAddRefPath Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Build\Lib1" />
    <MyAddRefPath Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Build\Lib2" />    
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyAddRefPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Build\Lib3</MyAddRefPath>
    <!-- add in the property path -->
    <AssemblySearchPaths>$(MyAddRefPath);$(AssemblySearchPaths)</AssemblySearchPaths>
    <!-- add in the item paths -->
    <AssemblySearchPaths>@(MyAddRefPath);$(AssemblySearchPaths)</AssemblySearchPaths>
</PropertyGroup>
```

...and if you do need to do this in a target to pick up paths from a dynamically populated item group, use inline properties, not the CreateProperty task (if you are not stuck in v2.0)

```
<Target Name="AddToSearchPaths">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- add in the item paths -->
        <AssemblySearchPaths>@(MyDynamicAddRefPath);$(AssemblySearchPaths)</AssemblySearchPaths>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: How does this script relate to the original script?

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I can't understand how this would work, what's the difference of $(MyAddRefPath) and @(MyAddRefPath) and what supposed to happen in these lines?

Comment: Anything with $() is a scalar property, anything with @() is a list of items, in this case the items are the paths.  When you reference an item list where a single value is needed, MSBuild will flatten the list into a comma delimited list, which is exactly what is expected in AssemblySearchPaths.  I was just showing that there are two ways to do this, your preference, you don't need to do both.