# referencing a dll in MSbuild

Tags: dll, msbuild

I have an application that I am trying to build through the command line with MSBuild.  This project will be built on a machine without a specific dll in the GAC (the dll it will need is in the GAC on the machine on which it is running on).  Is there a way that in the MSBuild command that I can have it referrence a dll in a folder?  Changing the proj file would require some changes in each of the projects that we use.  Is there a way to reference the dll in the MSBuild Command Line?

Comment: You *never* use assemblies from the GAC when you build a program.  Not with the Visual Studio IDE, not with MSBuild either.  The GAC only contains assemblies that are used at runtime.  Never build time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Additional paths in msbuild script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276435/additional-paths-in-msbuild-script)

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22383063/147211)

Comment: @Hans Passant
Normally I would agree with you, but I am looking at my referrences right now and it literally refers to an assembly in the GAC.

Comment: You need to fix that.